# Specifying k-fold cross validation using tune.svm() in R

Tags: r, svm

I have two lists of parameters (gamma and cost) that I want to select using a SVM. I want to do 5-fold crossvalidation, but my code makes 10-fold cross validation (which is the default).
My code is looking like this:

```
prioir_svm <- tune.svm(train, y = trainY, cost = Cs, gamma = gammas, cross = 5)
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
tc <- tune.control(cross = 5)

prioir_svm <- tune.svm(train, y = trainY, cost = Cs, gamma = gammas,
tunecontrol = tc)
```

see `?tune.control` for details